# How do I unlock my Nexus 5 without touching the screen to back up my pictures and videos before re-setting?

Tags: backup, touchscreen

My touch screen won't work at all and if I have to replace the screen,is it going to reset my phone. OR I just might buy a new phone, but to get my pictures and videos, I need to get my phone unlocked.

Comment: Is your N5 rooted?

Comment: no, I don't think so,I'm not even sure how to do that..?

Answer (score 1):

Get a USB OTG cable, and connect a standard USB mouse to your phone. You can use the mouse on the lockscreen; no need to enable anything in advance.

I tried this with http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B009DFCCKO and it worked perfectly with my Nexus 5. It took a few weeks to arrive from China, but luckily I wasn't in a hurry. I'm sure it's possible to get something similar sooner if you pay a little more.

To answer the other part of your question, there's no need to reset a device just to replace the screen (I changed the screen on my Nexus 7 without resetting it). But if it was me, I'd feel happier about sending it off for repair if I had all the photos safely backed up, just in case.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other place I can find that cable though?

Comment: You don't need that specific cable; it was just an example. Any USB OTG ("on the go", also called "host mode") cable with a micro USB plug should do. You'll need to search for one with faster delivery, or try a local electronics shop (wherever local is for you).